# Rails Associations for Lookup Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Statuses table which contains only an id and name field (Active, Inactive, Pending, etc).  I then have tables such as Users, Achievements, Badges for which each of these contain a status_id foreign key.  Do the associations in my models look correct?

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :achievements
  has_many :badges
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end

class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end

class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end
```

I am struggling with how to properly read the difference between has_one and has_many in the case of a lookup table. I know that a user has one company and has one profile and a company has many users but this seems backwards to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest association setup would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end
```

That exactly describes what you have posted.  Your solution would work,  but it is overkill for what you've described.  All the association I posted above would do is add one method to the user model, i.e.

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.status
```

If on the other hand you wanted simple semantics for showing all the users with a particular status,   THEN you'd add

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

so now you could do:

```
@status = Status.find_by_description('Active').first()

@status.users
```

Note that in BOTH cases,  all that is needed is for the users model to have an attribute 'status_id'

Belongs_to is better suited when there is an implicit hierarchy , i,e,

```
class Child << ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :parent
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  With regards to belongs_to... I did read some documentation on the rails site that says the table containing the foreign key contains the belongs_to in the model.

Comment: That is true,  but the question is do you need the semantics introduced by belongs_to ?  i.e. a user has one status,  but does a status belong to a user?  No a status does not belong to a user, status can be assigned to a number of users,  so you probably would never need the query semantics that says,  show me the user that belongs to this status.

Comment: that was actually a very good way to explain it.  thanks much!